# Open link in new tab instead of clicking the element found by Class Name| Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, screen-scraping

This is the link

```
https://www.unibet.eu/betting/sports/filter/football/matches
```

Using selenium driver, I access this link. This is what we have on the page

[image: Sample_Image]

The actual task for me is to click on each of the match link. I found all those matches by

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('eb700')
```

When i did this

```
for elem in elems:
elements
elem.click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
time.sleep(2)
```

The first time it clicked, loaded new page, went to previous page and then gave the following error

```
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

I also tried getting HREF attribute from the elem, but it gave None, Is it possible to open the page in a new tab instead of clicking the elem?

Comment: why is 'elements' in the for loop (it is not assigned to any value, remove it)

Comment: Please use proper indentation, it helps us to understand the code easier  : )

Answer (score 0):

Since you move to next page, the elements no longer exists in DOM. So, you will get Stale Element exception.
What you can do is when comming back to same page, get all the links again (elems) and use while loop instead of for loop.

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('eb700')
i=0
while i<len(elems):
    elems[i].click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
    time.sleep(2)
    elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('eb700')
    i++
```

Other solution is to remain on same page and save all href attributes in a list and then use driver.navigate to open each match link.

```
matchLinks=[]
elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('eb700')
for elem in elems:
    matchLinks.append(elem.get_attribute('href')
for match in matchLinks:
    driver.get(match)
    #do whatever you want to do on match page.
```

Comment: This is a good solution. But you need to write bit of code to let OP understand fully

Comment: Hi, both the solution you provided, i had them in my mind and I tried both of them, 
For the second solution you mentioned, I already said in the question that i Got None from get_attribute('href')

Comment: I have checked the website, href attribute is not present even no a tag that's why href gives nothing. But I even tried to click the match and it is also doing nothing. When you right click, there is no option of opening it in new tab. But while loop method should work if you are able navigate to new page.

Answer (score 0):

You can retry to click on element once again since it is no longer present in DOM.

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\**\\Inc\\Desktop\\Selenium+Python\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.unibet.eu/betting/sports/filter/football/matches")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "OK"))).click()
sleep(2)
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'_')]/div[@data-test-name='accordionLevel1']")
element_len = len(elements)
print(element_len)
counter = 0
while counter < element_len:
    attempts = 0
    while attempts < 2:
        try:
            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elements[counter]).click().perform()
        except:
            pass
        attempts = attempts + 1
    sleep(2)
   # driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)") #may be get team name 
   #using //div[@data-test-name='teamName'] xpath 
    sleep(2)
   # driver.refresh()
    sleep(2)
    counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: How will this solution overcome the stale element problem? You are still clicking those elements so as after opening the first link and then going back the rest of link elements will now stale elements

Comment: @Prophet : No when you click on the first element it does not redirect to new page or a link as you can see `# driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")` is commented out. I have tried this code and it works pretty much fine on my machine.

Comment: I can't run this since I have no Python on my machine :) I see that you commented out the  `driver.back` but isn't `ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elements[counter]).click().perform()` open the href as in the original code?

Comment: @Prophet : `"//div[contains(@class,'_')]/div[@data-test-name='accordionLevel1']` see this xpath, I didn't see anchor tag in that table where OP wants to scroll and click. It does not redirect at all. I don't know why OP had written code to go back to previous page. Even if it redirects for few links then OP might wanna try `driver.refresh()` to resolve staleness of element.

Comment: Maybe I didn't catch the point as you had, but what I see - the OP is looking for elements located by class `eb700` and these are already opened accordion elements. I mean, in the initial state there are only 2 open accordions there, clicking on any of them performing the redirection causing the stale element problem. While you getting 75 closed accordions and only expanding them. Now, if you will click on any one of the accordions you opened this will redirect you as in the original question and this, as I see, the point here.

Comment: @Prophet : `I mean, in the initial state there are only 2 open accordions there` - 100% true. Wouldn't uncommenting `refresh` the web page will resolve the staleness issue ?

Comment: I don't know. I currently have to work, have no time to debug this, but it seems to me that this is an interesting and not a simple issue.